# difference in sybase versions

Tags: sybase

What differs in the stored procedures between sybase version 12.5 and version 15

Comment: Do you perhaps mean between versions 12.5 and 15?

Comment: yes I mean versions 12.5 and 15

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [procedures reference manual for v15](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/title.htm), and here it is for [version 12.5](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dc36271_36272_36273_36274_1250/html/refman/title.htm)... or you might find the [What's New in Adaptive Server Enterprise?](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.whatsnew/html/whatsnew/title.htm) guide has some specifics so you don't have to do the comparison yourself. Happy reading!

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoul specify your need. For example if you intend to ask "what is the declaration difference?". The answer could be like below:

```
Sybase ASE 15.7
create procedure [owner.]procedure_name[;number]
    [[(@parameter_name datatype [(length) | (precision [, scale])]
        [= default][output]
    [, @parameter_name datatype [(length) | (precision [, scale])]
        [= default][output]]...)]]
    [with {recompile | execute as {owner | caller}} ]
    as {SQL_statements | external name dll_name}



Sybase ASE 12.5
create procedure [owner.]procedure_name[;number]
    [[(]@parameter_name datatype [(length ) | (precision  [, scale ])]
        [= default][output]
    [, @parameter_name datatype [(length ) | (precision  [, scale ])]
        [= default][output]]...[)]]
    [with recompile] 
    as {SQL_statements | external name dll_name}
```